# Changing IE proxy settings in Windows CE device programmatically

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, visual-c++, proxy, windows-ce

I'm creating a Win32 application which will change the proxy settings.I followed this article [How to programmatically query and set proxy settings under Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473).

While trying this code snippet:

```
unsigned long        nSize = 4096;
char                 szBuf[4096] = { 0 };
INTERNET_PROXY_INFO* pInfo = (INTERNET_PROXY_INFO*)szBuf;
if(!InternetQueryOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, pInfo, &nSize))
   printf("InternetQueryOption failed! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
```

The pInfo->lpszProxy contains strange symbols. I tried searching the registry for the proxy settings but could not find it as well. In the article mentioned above, there was one more snippet to retrieve the proxy settings:

```
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST    List;
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION         Option[5];
unsigned long                    nSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);

Option[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL;
Option[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS;
Option[2].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
Option[3].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
Option[4].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;

List.dwSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
List.pszConnection = NULL;
List.dwOptionCount = 5;
List.dwOptionError = 0;
List.pOptions = Option;

if(!InternetQueryOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &List, &nSize))
  printf("InternetQueryOption failed! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
```

While trying the above snipped, I get the proxy details as ":80". Has anyone faced similar issue with Windows CE? If yes, were you able to solve it? Is there a way I can change the proxy settings in Windows CE? What am I missing in the above snippets?